# How to get cmake-generated Makefile to echo compiler command-lines?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, makefile

On Linux I can build a C++ project with cmake like:

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ../myproject
$ make
[  ] Building CXX object ...
```

Is there a way to pass an option to cmake or make so that it will print the full command-lines (and all the options) it is passing to the C++ compiler to compile each object file?

(I tried:

```
$ make V=1
```

but it doesn't seem to work.  I guess the cmake-generated Makefile doesn't work with that option?)

Comment: Any particular reason why you use make and not `cmake --build`?

Comment: @infinitezero: Yes - because I didn't know the `--build` option existed. :)

Comment: Try adding this flag to your first cmake command: `cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON ../myproject`

Comment: Or anything else from this link: https://bytefreaks.net/programming-2/make-building-with-cmake-verbose?amp=1

Comment: @infinitezero: The Answer The Question button is little further down the page.

Comment: as I did not know if it would actually work (couldn't test it), and if it did what you actually wanted. I didnt want to make an answer, which implies I do not know what I'm talking about (which I don't :) ).

Answer (score 2):

As per [this link](https://bytefreaks.net/programming-2/make-building-with-cmake-verbose?amp=1) There are three options (+1 extra found in the answer of HolyBlackCat):

## 1

If you can / want to modify the `CMakeLists.txt`, you can just add

```
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
```

This has to be done in *every* CMakeLists.txt file in your project though, so it might be a bit cumbersome, if you want to enable it for the entire project.

## 2

To write the verbose changes directly to the makefile, you can run the cmake command which generates the make file with an additional flag:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON ./path
```

And, you guessed it, to disable it, you need to run it again:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=OFF ./path
```

## 3

Finally, if you build your project by calling `make` and do not use the `cmake --build ./path`  or `cmake --build ./path --target target` commands, you can pass it as an option to `make` directly:

```
make VERBOSE=1;
```

Although I would not recommend it, because they whole point of cmake is to not have to use make anymore (although it's still called behind the scenes).

Answer (score 1):

Use either `make VERBOSE=1`, or `cmake --build <path> --verbose` which automatically invokes the right command for the generator you used.